# Use Python Anaconda and Python Homebrew on a Mac computer?

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, anaconda

I have Anaconda Python installed on my Mac MBA, but I also use  Homebrew to install packages not available from Anaconda.

How to switch Python and pip to the Anaconda or  Homebrew? Just use the full path link, or make alias, or .....?

Thanks

Comment: You mean you use pip to install packages not found by conda? Homebrew doesn't install python libraries

Comment: I need to install a package which has a python binding, the installation procedures are as follow, not sure if the brew installation will cause interferences with my Anaconda python installation. Thanks
`brew tap homebrew/science
# openalpr v2.2.0 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/3073)
brew install openalpr
# install HEAD
brew install --HEAD openalpr`

Comment: openalpr seems like a separate python program. Should run with your system python, or might work on your environment variables.

Comment: Looks one simple way to handle both Anaconda and Homebrew on a Mac computer is to change $PATH so that Anaconda was removed temporarily when using Homebrew. When you need to use Anaconda Python then add back the Anaconda. This worked for me so far. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Anaconda, then paste and run pip from there:

```
./pip install elasticsearch
```